# Find all the contents between two tags in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

```
<p>This is the first paragraph with some details</p>
<p><a href = "user123">user1</a><font>This is opening contents for user1</font></p>
<p><font>This is the contents from user1</font></p>
<font><p>This is more content from user1</p></font>
<p><a href = "user234">user2</a><font>This is opening contents for user2</font></p>
<p><font>This is the contents from user2</font></p>
<font><p>This is more content from user1</p></font>
!----There is n number of data like this-----!
```

This is the structure of my html. My aim is to extract the users and their contents. In this case it should print all the contents between two 'a' tags. This is just an example of my structure, but in real html, i have different types of tags between two 'a' tags. I need a solution to iterate all the tags below a 'a' tag till it finds another 'a' tag. Hope thats clear.

The code which i tried is :

```
for i in soup.findAll('a'):
    while(i.nextSibling.name!='a'):
        print i.nextSibling
```

I returns me an infinite loop. So if anyone has idea how i can solve this issue please share it with me.

Expected output is :

username is : user1

text is : This is opening contents for user1 This is the contents from user1 This is more content from user1

username is : user2

text is : This is opening contents for user2 This is the contents from user2 This is more content from user2

and so on......

Comment: You are missing the closing `</p>` in lines 2 and 4.  Is that a mistake in your example, or is it really so?

Comment: The reason why you're getting an infinite loop is that you're not iterating through `i`'s siblings, you're looking at the same sibling every time.

Comment: @nickie --thats by mistake..i have corrected it now...

Comment: OK, then I think my solution works.

Comment: After your last edit, tags `<p>` and `<font>` in lines 4 and 7 are impoperly nested.

Comment: ok..i fixed it again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""
<p>This is the first paragraph with some details</p>
<p><a href="user123">user1</a><font>This is opening contents for user1</font></p>
<p><font>This is the contents from user1</font></p>
<font><p>This is more content from user1</p></font>
<p><a href="user234">user2</a><font>This is opening contents for user2</font></p>
<p><font>This is the contents from user2</font></p>
<font><p>This is more content from user1</p></font>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for i in soup.find_all('a'):
  print 'name:', i.text
  for s in [i, i.parent.find_next_sibling()]:
    while s <> None:
      if s.find('a') <> None:
        break
      print 'contents:', s.text
      s = s.find_next_sibling()
```

(Note: `find_all` is the recommended name for `findAll`, it may not work in older soups.  Same with `find_next_sibling`.)

Comment: @nickie- Thanks. But this will only fetch the immediate next tag. I have clarified my requirements now. I hope my new edited question will be more clear .

Comment: Fixed the answer too, then.

Comment: @nickie-Thank you very much..it works better than before. Since i am working with large data i came up with another situation where there is a 'font' tag inside 'a' tag which also contains some content. Which according to your solution doesnt get displayed. for e.g. <p><a href = "user123">user1</a><font>This is opening content for user1</font></p> . I also updated the original question so that its clear. Thanks

Comment: Fixed again.  This is becoming too much and I'll stop here.  I believe you've got the picture.  Cheers...

Comment: works fine now..and i also got to learn new stuff...sorry i am just learning python so had lots of doubts..but now its cleared..Thank you very much..

Answer (score 1):

One option is to search for every `<a>` tag with `find_all()` and for each link use `find_all_next()` to search `<font>` tags that have the contents for each user. The following script extracts the user name and its contents and save both as a tuple inside a list:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

l = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('htmlfile'))
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    s = []
    for elem in link.find_all_next(['font', 'a']):
        if elem.name == 'a':
            break
        s.append(elem.string)
    user_content = ' '.join(s)
    l.append((link.string, user_content))
```

It yields:

```
[('user1', 'This is the contents from user1 This is more content from user1'),
 ('user2', 'This is the contents from user2 This is more content from user2')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But it yields only some of the field. Suppose there are different tags names between two 'a' tags and i want to extract all the contents of those tag. It is a problem because my html is very inconsistent. I am looking for something which extracts all data until it finds another 'a' tag

Comment: @user2657822: Do you mean to extract all text between `<a>` tags? Why don't you add the expected output to your question? It will be more clear.

Comment: @Birei-I have edited it now. Hope its clear. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @user2657822: I've edited the answer. Note that I had to fix your example data, the `<p>` and `<font>` tags are mixed in some lines.

Comment: @user2657822: Output is the expected for me.

Comment: Maybe its because my html has unusual format..But thank you very much for the idea..i shall use it someday